# KSH for loop works on Solaris/Mac but not on Red Hat Linux

Tags: for-loop, ksh

The following Ksh script gives me "No such file or directory" error message on Red Hat Linux system.  Does anyone has a solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for f in `cat files.dat`
do
  wc $f
done
```

For example, `files.dat` has 3 lines of data and each line is a file in the current directory where the script is running from.

```
a.c
a.h
b.c
```

Note, the same for loop generated the same error message if running from command line too.

It works on Solaris/Mac box but not on Red Hat system.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the error "No such file or directory" generated for ksh or for files.dat?

Comment: The error is for a.c, a.h, and b.c since `cat files.dat` is equivalent to a.c a.h b.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for ... cat`, you should use

```
while read -r f
do
    wc "$f"
done < files.dat
```

And you should use `$()` instead of backticks when you do need to do command substitution.

But your problem is probably that the files `a.c`, etc., are not there, have different names, invisible characters in their names, or the line endings in `files.dat` are CR/LF (DOS/Windows-style) instead of `\n` (LF only - Unix-style) or there are odd characters in the file otherwise.

Comment: The original files.dat was created using redirect output from find command which caused the error.  I did verify the contents of this file using "od -c" command but there is no weird character.  Anyway, thanks for the prompt replies.

Answer (score 1):

You should properly quote your arguments, in other words, use `"$f"`, not `$f`.
About cat - it's mostly documented in here: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

What is probably better suited is `xargs -a thatfile wc`.

Comment: The intent is to use egrep to match some patterns on $f and redirect output of grep to a file but I got this error.  Then I tried to just run wc and got the same error.  Since I don't have access to RH Box now so I will try "$f" tomorrow.  Thanks.